# Increase size /opt

Tags: partitioning

I'm trying to install IBM DS Storage Manager 10 on an Ubuntu 12.04 but it seems I doesn't have enough opt space. Below is the screenshot from the required/available disk space:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it even possible to resize the /opt? I always thought that a folder could be as big as the amount of free space you have. I have more than enough space on my hard drive (about 190GB) so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: did you have a seperate `/opt` partition?

Comment: No, just did a default install

Comment: As @AvinashRaj asked very correctly, If you have a separate /opt partition (very rare nowadays) you can resize this partition only. If not, you have to resize the entire root partition. See multiple answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60431/how-do-i-resize-root-partition), none is detailed explained, but you will get the basic idea.

Comment: Hmm, still find it weird to be honest. I have more than enough free space on the partition where opt is located so why should resizing make any difference?

Comment: @TimothyPersoon :=D Yeah well I live in a comma decimal country so these things catch my eye quickly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problems.

- 505 Mb required
- 185806 Mb free = roughly 190Gb

Comment: Damn, I can't believe I didn't see that myself... Keen eye! @Rinzwind