# Trouble shooting for ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have upgraded my system from ubuntu 14.04 Lts to 14.10 ,after the upgrading the system is showing some internal error with 14.10 version and asking to reboot the system.I rebot the system even though i am getting the same problem please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) "Some error" can be quite easily fixed by doing "something",  so please add the exact error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize root partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60431/how-do-i-resize-root-partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access you system with something like Parted Magic
Here is a version you could try
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10573557/pmagic_2013_08_01.iso

Be careful.
But you might want to access your /home/username*
To backup stuff

I often use this tool to clear config files in a user profile, (that's the hidden files in your user account)

Did you upgrade 14.04 > 14.10 seem to go well, without error?

Comment: yes i upgraded after that i am facing the internal error problem. And can you please tell the pmagic is a os or a tool to backup the data.

Comment: It's a OS. It runs from a USB or a CD

Comment: ok thanks carl but what this pmagic os will do

Comment: Carl, please: 1/ Don't ask for more information in an answer. There is a reason beginning users cannot comment. 2/ Don't post multiple answers, but [edit] your previous answer to include the new information. 3/ take the [tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) 4/ Also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future...

Comment: @Fabby Sorry.-  Parted Magic can give you unfettered access to all your files, just so you can make a backup, which you should have done in the first place. Also it's worth considering, if you didn't already, creating /home as a separate partition. Think about that next time you do an installation from scratch.

Comment: I know!  It's Sanjay that doesn't.  (I'm just a reviewer trying to smooth things out)  **;-)**

Comment: I also know that. LOL