# How do I extend mint root partition using a previous un allocated size?

Tags: root, gparted, partitioning, resize, unallocated

[image: GParted scrrenshot]

I want to extend `sda5` using `sda8` with out losing any data.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: However, questions about using Ubuntu to resize partitions while conserving the integrity of other OS is on topic. ;-]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize root partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60431/how-do-i-resize-root-partition)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: true!  (I wish I could change everyone's vote to a duplicate

Comment: @Fabby: Let's vote to re-open then.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: voted: remind me to vote to close again too, please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resize an ext root partition at runtime?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime)

Comment: @Fabby reminder to close :D

Comment: I can apparently only vote to close once... @Ravan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to resize any partitions that are actively in use (i.e. the packaged version of Gparted is typically used for changing partitions of external storage devices).

To extend your partition, you should reboot into a live environment. The Gparted project provides one such Debian-based [live ISO](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) that is used for this purpose. Simply burn the ISO to any boot-able media:

for CDs use `sudo dd if=/path/to/gparted-live-xxxxx.iso of=/dev/sr0`

for USB devices use `sudo dd if=/path/to/gparted-live-xxxxx.iso of=/dev/sdX`, where X is the letter of your particular device. Make sure this is correctly identified. USB devices are usually NOT `/dev/sda`.

for DVDs use `sudo wodim -eject -tao dev=/dev/sr0 /path/to/gparted-live-xxxxx.iso`