# Increase the root partition size on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: command-line, server, partitioning, root

How can I increase the root partition size of a virtualized Ubuntu Server 14.04 using the CLI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize root partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60431/how-do-i-resize-root-partition)